# HtmlAgilityPack img src not loading

Tags: c#, xaml, html-agility-pack, windows-10, uwp

I am using HtmlAgilityPack in a Windows 10 UWP app, most links work great, adding a new link but the img src does not come down. Everything else does. What am I doing wrong?

Source (you can see the src attribute is there, this is copied from browser):

```
<img alt="Image" class="absoluteImage" data-reactid=".wrncnqzp4w.$profile-view.$view-content.$profile.$grid.0.0.$container.$creation-7226049.$link.$idea.$image.$image" src="http://linkishere.com">
```

What I get when I scrape it (the src attribute is missing):

```
<img alt="Image" class="absoluteImage" data-reactid=".1kajwg0fg8w.$profile-view.$view-content.$profile.$grid.0.0.$container.$creation-7226049.$link.$idea.$image.$image">
```

The src attribute is missing entirely.

Code here:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(TypeLink);

IEnumerable<HtmlNode> items = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.ToLower().Contains("creationitem"));
foreach (var li in items)
{
   if(count <= 10)
   {
      //count++;
      SiteItem item = new SiteItem();
      //item.title = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(li.Attributes["title"].Value);
      foreach (var child in li.DescendantsAndSelf())
      {
         if(child.Attributes.Contains("class") && child.Attributes["class"].Value.ToLower().Contains("creation-link"))
         {
            item.link = child.Attributes["href"].Value;
         }

         if (child.Attributes.Contains("class") && child.Attributes["class"].Value.ToLower().Contains("absoluteimage"))
         {
            item.image150 = child.Attributes["src"].Value;
         }
      }
   others.Add(item);
```

}
                        }

Comment: My pick would be that react (a Javascript framework), is adding in the src attribute of the image. If the src attribute is not present when you "View Source" in the browser, it will not be loaded from "LoadFromWebAsync". As far as I am aware HtmlAgilityPack doesn't run the Javascript and you're going to have to find an alternative method of retrieving the image source.